# how to make layer tree in Openlayers 3?

Tags: openlayers-3

I am trying to make a Layer tree that contains all the layers in my web application. I want the layer tree with opacity slider and functionality to re-arrange the layers (ordering of the layers).

[image]

me how can I do this?

Comment: This is HTML, CSS and JS work. As far as I know, there's nothing ready.

Answer (score 0):

your example is from map.geo.admin.ch. Ask them in their google group (https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!forum/geoadmin-api) for a link to the code. It is open source